# Two Onclick functions, ajax/php or JS. What get called first?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, encryption

I have this script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sha512.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="forms.js"></script>

<script>
            function loadXMLDoc(form, password) 
            {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
               {
                   document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                   formhash(form, password);
               }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("POST","post.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            }
</script>
```

And this html:

```
    <div id="myDiv">
<form action="register.php" method="post">
   Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
   Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
   Password: <input type="password" name="p" id="password" /><br />
   <input type="button" value="Register" onclick="loadXMLDoc(this.form, this.form.password);" />
</form>
</div>
```

As you might have noticed, the onclick runs two functions once the button is pressed. The first function is the one you can see above, it's a javascript code that runs ajax with some PHP in it. The other function is 100 % Javascript and it encrypts the password field.

My problem is that I can't get it to run the PHP before the password is encrypted with the formhash function.

The reason I need this, is because I need PHP to check if the password is NOT empty before the password is encrypted. I thought that maybe the PHP gets run after all the javascript from the formhash function is run, which is too late. I need the first function in "onclick" to be run first, and the other second. Did I do something wrong, or is it as I excpected?

EDIT:
Wauw, I had one "{" too much. Now it works I think, but it doesn't remember what the user has posted in the form. So I can't make something like this:

```
<?php
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
            echo "<p>Test</p>";
        }
?>
```

Because it don't know the email post anymore.

Comment: Do not put the function definition of `formhash` but the actual *call* into the success part of the `readystatechange` function. I.e. leave out the word `function` and make sure you supply the function call with valid arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<input type="button" value="Register" onclick="loadXMLDoc(this.form, this.form.password);" />

<script>
function loadXMLDoc(frm, pass) {
   .....
   .....
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
       document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

       formhash(frm, pass);
   }
   .....
   .....
}

function formhash(frm, pass)
{
    //password encryption script here.
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is basically it! But you probably mean your onclick event to call `loadXMLDoc` instead of `formhash`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, best observation, it is corrected. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried adding this to my function, apart from the place where it says "//password encryption script here." is everything else right? And do I have to put this actual script there and delete my form.js file which contains that function normally?

Comment: No need to add formhash() { //password encryption script here. }  from yourself if it is already in your form.js file. It should work from your file.

Comment: So it should work as it is now? (editted the post). I don't really know much JS so it's hard to understand how it works.

Comment: Hm, nothing seems to happen when I press the Register button. My post.php looks like this: 
<?php
echo "Test";
?>
I don't know if that has anything to do with it, or maybe its the sha512 function?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `formhash` function to be called after your Ajax call is ready then you should put the function call into the `readystatechange` function of your Ajax call.

By simply placing it in the onclick event of the button, after the `loadXMLDoc()` call you will not achieve the desired effect, since the Ajax function works *asynchronously* (the 'A' in 'Ajax') ...

**Edit:**

With Ajax you need to send the form data explicitely since you are not submitting it as part of your form action:

```
...
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
               {
                   document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                   formhash(form, password);
               }
              }
xmlhttp.open("POST","post.php",true);
xmlhttp.send('email='+documents.getElementById('email').value);
...
```

For this to work you need to identify the `email` input field in your HTML with an `id` attribute like

```
...
Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br />
...
```

And (even though this is not really wanted here at Stackoverflow ...) a final word of advice: It *is possible* to do everything with just 'plain' JavaScript, but you can make life so much more easy for yourself if you start working with jQuery ("write less, do more").

Comment: I have tried adding a function inside onreadystatechange, is that what you meant?

Comment: I was basically suggesting what Salim has put into writing in the meantime :-)

Comment: I am still struggeling with this, I have now editted some more, I believe it should be like this? That makes sense to me at least, but nothing happens when I press the register button, any ideas?